# How to retrieve JSON object elements with variables?

Tags: jquery, getjson

Using `$.getJSON`, I've got a very large result which contains elements for each of our products.  I need to access some of the properties using variables, but can't manage to figure out the jQuery syntax to do so.

```
$.getJSON("datasource.php",function(licensed){
    // Hardcoded works
    alert ( licensed.product5200.order_id );

    // How to use a variable instead, something like this:
    var MyVar = "product5200";
    alert ( licensed.MyVar.order_id );
});
```

EDIT: Is there a way to determine if "product5200" exist before I begin working with it?
    `console.info('Is It There?:' + licensed['product5200'].hasOwnProperty);`

ANSWER: `console.info('Is It There?:' + licensed.hasOwnProperty('product5200'));`

**JSON Object** (*shown as a PHP array for clarity only*)

```
[licensed] => Array
    (
        [product5200] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 5200
                [order_id] => 159004882
            )
        [product5204] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 5204
                [order_id] => 159004882
            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array-access notation on objects as well.

```
licensed[MyVar].order_id
```

should work.

By the way, I would suggest `console.log` over `alert`, especially in Chrome (which lets you inspect the contents of the logged object).

Comment: Ah...started down the path of Arrays to begin with, but as I learn this stuff, the googling gets me down a specifc path.  BTW, I generally do use console - I use alert when I don't want to lose track of something I'm working on - it nags me until I finish it, lol

Comment: And thank you, btw....KevinB actually answered it first, so I have to accept his answer, but +1 for yours as a consolation! :)

Comment: @GDP it says I answered 8 minutes ago and he answered 9 minutes ago

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the question was asked, and an answer was found. :)

Comment: @KevinB I was just more curious as to whether he sees a different time for answers or something

Comment: It is odd, i do see mine is about a minute sooner.

Comment: I'm seeing it the other way, but will extend the question a bit as tie breaker, lol

Comment: where did KevinB's answer go? @ExplosionPills "it says I answered 8 minutes ago and he answered 9 minutes ago" - this makes KevinB the first to answer like GDP mentioned

Comment: @Steve oh yeah; I guess I forgot how to count